# Use a function of component in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

i have my CodeMirror component on svelte and i need to use some functions (declared inside the component) where i use the codemirror to change the value. For example:

```
export function update(new_value) {

value = new_value;

if (editor) {
  const { left, top } = editor.getScrollInfo();
  editor.setValue((value = new_value));
  editor.scrollTo(left, top);
}


 }
```

How can I import and use it where i declare CodeMirror? I tried to use

```
 import CodeMirror, {update} from '../../../../components/CodeMirror.svelte';
```

but is not working

Answer (score 2):

Given you are exporting the function, you should be able to use [bind:this](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element) to call the function on the instance of the component. You would create a variable that you can reference in the `bind:this` statement, then you can call the exported function `update` against that component:

```
let codeMirrorComponent;

function someHandler() {
  // may want to check `if (codeMirrorComponent && codeMirrorComponent.update)` to ensure function is available to call
  codeMirrorComponent.update('someValue');
}

<CodeMirror bind:this={codeMirrorComponent} />
```

Here is [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2c6d09238de940949aa1f4869f9822e8?version=3.31.0) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I understand everything and where i commit errors, thanks!